# how to match the values in array and push the array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Here below is my code.

I'm trying to plot graph values using the below array.
On the `dates` array i have all 30 days in the array.
I have another array called `pending_date` and `approved_date`.
I need to match the date.Add the key and value for the matching key(date) array. Can u tell me where I'm going wrong ?

```
$approved_date = array('2017-09-01'=>'1','2017-09-02' => '2', '2017-09-03' => '4');
$pending_date = array('2017-09-01'=>'2');
$rejected_date = array();
```

**Tried Code**

```
        $myYearMonth = date('Y-m');
        $start = new DateTime(date('Y-m-01', strtotime($myYearMonth)));
        $end = new DateTime(date('Y-m-t', strtotime($myYearMonth)).' +1 day');
        $diff = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
        $periodStart = new DatePeriod($start, $diff, $end);

        foreach ( $periodStart as $dayDate ){
         $dates[]['period'] = $dayDate->format( "Y-m-d" );
        }

        foreach( $pending_date as $key => $value ){
          $data_key = array_search( $key, $dates );
          if( $data_key !== false ) $dates[ $data_key ] = $value;
        }
```

**Expected Output**

```
{"period": "2017-09-01", "approved": 1, "pending": 2, "rejected": 0},
{"period": "2017-09-02", "approved": 2, "pending": 0, "rejected": 0},
{"period": "2017-09-03", "approved": 4, "pending": 0, "rejected": 0}
```

Comment: You've provided expected output, but what's your current output?

Comment: I'm confused on the pushing array on particular array value..

Comment: Then how can i acheive with the expected output ? "period": "2017-09-01"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$approved_date = array('2017-09-01'=>'1','2017-09-02' => '2', '2017-09-03' => '4');
$pending_date = array('2017-09-01'=>'2');
$rejected_date = array();

$dates = array();
//$periods = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($approved_date), array_keys($pending_date), array_keys($rejected_date)));
$periods = array(); // fill $periods how you like
for($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) {
    $periods[] = '2017-09-' . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
foreach ($periods as $period) {
    $dates[] = array(
        'period' => $period,
        'approved' => isset($approved_date[$period]) ? $approved_date[$period] : 0,
        'pending' => isset($pending_date[$period]) ? $pending_date[$period] : 0,
        'rejected' => isset($rejected_date[$period]) ? $rejected_date[$period] : 0,
    );
}

echo json_encode($dates);
```

Comment: almost done.. But the thing is. i need all 30 days in this array. how can i do that ?

Comment: You wrote "On the dates array i have all 30 days in the array."... So you need to get all 30 days?

Comment: shall i add this one "foreach ( $periodStart as $dayDate ){
                $dates[] = $dayDate->format( "Y-m-d" );
            }"?

Comment: You can fill `$periods` how you like. I updated code with example. Now it generate 30 days.